# Is block address used to choose the set in set associative cache physical address?

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture

Page 74 in [Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach, 5th edition, by Hennessy and Patterson](http://store.elsevier.com/Computer-Architecture/David-Patterson/isbn-9780123838728/) gives the following formula to choose the set:

> (Block address) MOD (Number of sets in cache)

Is `Block address` physical address or virtual address? I think that it should be physical address. Is my understanding right?

Comment: Caches can be virtually or physically indexed.  Either one is a valid design choice, especially for an L1 cache.

Comment: L2 and higher caches are almost always PIPT.  (For L1 caches, [a common trick](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38549736/224132) is to have high few enough sets that the index bits of the address all come from the offset-within-a-page part of the address, i.e. they're translated for free so you get the speed of VIPT but the behaviour of a PIPT cache as far as homonym / synonym aliasing problems).

Comment: @PeterCordes Could you give some references about how Intel Haswell processors use addresses in its L1, L2 and L3 caches?

Comment: [David Kanter's SnB writeup mentions L1 using VIPT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19059970/224132).  @Paul Clayton says [he's never heard of a conventional architecture using anything but PIPT for L2/L3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33974193/does-x86-64-cpu-use-the-same-chache-lines-for-communicate-between-2-processes-vi/33977591?noredirect=1#comment55733230_33977591), which makes sense, see the discussion in comments and updated answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks a lot