# Effect of memory ordering instructions on x86/x86_64 multiple sockets

Tags: caching, multiprocessing, x86-64, memory-model

Tried looking for the answer to this question in the Intel 64/IA-32, but couldn't find a definitive answer. Questions is: Do memory ordering instructions, such as SFENCE, have effect on the local processor only, or do they spread to the entire cache coherence domain, such as CPUs on a neighboring socket (in a multi-socket system)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SFENCE` affects the order in which the local CPU's stores become globally visible to other cores on the same and other sockets, or to memory-mapped I/O.

Other cores can't tell whether you ran `SFENCE` or not, all they can observe is the order of your memory operations.  (i.e. the implementation of `sfence` is internal to a core and its store queue).

`sfence` was introduced in SSE1, with PIII, before the first multi-core CPUs.  At that time, the only SMP systems were multi-socket.

Also note that it only does anything useful with weakly-ordered stores (`movnt*` or stores to write-combining memory regions).  Normal stores have ["release" semantics](http://%20It%20does%20this%20by%20putting%20barriers%20in%20the%20store%20queue,%20not%20by%20telling%20other%20CPU) already on x86.  Only `mfence` (and `lock`ed instructions) matter for normal memory operations on x86, [to prevent StoreLoad reordering](http://preshing.com/20120515/memory-reordering-caught-in-the-act/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Very helpful.

Comment: @dsaada: if that answers your question, you can use the check-mark under the vote arrows to mark it accepted.

Comment: Thanks. Did that. Just a complementary question - you were saying that other _cores_ aren't aware of fence instructions such as **SFENCE**. Does this apply also to other threads in the same core?

Comment: @dsaada: `MFENCE` is a more interesting example, because it matters even for "normal" stores/loads.  As far as observable effects, you can't tell.  Two hyperthreads communicating with each other on the same physical core has [a very complicated implementation which preserves all the expected semantics while still competitively sharing L1 cache.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32979067/what-will-be-used-for-data-exchange-between-threads-are-executing-on-one-core-wi/32981256#32981256).   Within one core, those barriers would have to be tracked by the memory-order buffer or something.