# What does it mean that "two store are seen in a consistent order by other processors"?

Tags: memory, x86, intel, memory-barriers, memory-model

In intel's manual:

section of : "8.2.2 Memory Ordering in P6 and More Recent Processor Families"

> Any two stores are seen in a consistent order by processors other than those performing the stores

what's meaning of this statement ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means no IRIW reordering (Independent Readers, Independent Writers; at least 4 separate cores, at least 2 each writers and readers).  2 readers will always agree on the order of any 2 stores performed other cores.

Weaker memory models *don't* guarantee this, for example ISO C++11 only guarantees it for `seq_cst` operations, not for `acq_rel` or any weaker orders.

A few hardware memory models allow it on paper, including ARM before ARMv8.  But in practice it's very rare POWER hardware can actually violate this in practice: See my answer [Will two atomic writes to different locations in different threads always be seen in the same order by other threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807118/will-two-atomic-writes-to-different-locations-in-different-threads-always-be-see/50679223#50679223) for an explanation of a hardware mechanism that can make it happen (store-forwarding between SMT "hyperthreads" on the same physical core making a store visible to some cores before it's globally visible).

x86 forbids this so communication between hyperthreads has to wait for commit to L1d cache, i.e. waiting for the store to be *globally* visible (thanks to MESI) before *any* other core can see it.  [What will be used for data exchange between threads are executing on one Core with HT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32979067/what-will-be-used-for-data-exchange-between-threads-are-executing-on-one-core-wi)